# How to find and enable fault input pins on AVR Timer/Counter-D (TCD)?

Tags: microcontroller, timer, programming, firmware, peripheral

My application requires that my PWM outputs have an asynchronous and fast acting "fault" input that pulls the outputs low as soon as a fault is detected. AVR's "TCD" timer has these inputs, and is available on the MCU that I want to use, the AVR64DD32.

The problem is that while the timer's outputs are clearly defined via a table, showing you exactly which pins and alternate pins can be used, the fault inputs that I need to use (called Event Input A and Event Input B) do not have any given pins, and I cannot find a hint in the documentation to point me.

It is crucial that these inputs work asynchronously so that the timer's outputs are disabled fast (before the MCU core has time to realize anything has happened), so this cannot be done via interrupts, that's why I wanted an MCU with this specific timer.

What pins are used for these fault inputs? How do I enable this function in code?

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what problem this is?  I read the question and the answer and it's not clear to me what you're solving.  Two PWM outputs sounds straightfforward.  "A fault input" sounds like an input to the MCU, perhaps connected to interrupt or just monitored, which woudl also be straightfoward.  From the length of your answer, I've obviously I've missed the problem, but I'm very curious.

Comment: @jonathanjo Sure, no problem. This microcontroller includes a timer peripheral with an asynchronous fault input, the core is **not** part of the decision to turn the timer off, as this is a safety feature (to stop the system from harming something or itself). There is often no time for even a single cycle, hence it's part of the peripheral itself. My problem was that you expect a peripheral's input to have a well defined pin, but turns out it is routed through another peripheral called the event system (EVSYS), and the documentation doesnt point you that way.

Comment: I have edited the question, please let me know if it is clearer

Comment: Ah now I start to see it.  Did you consider a gate on the output of the PWM, driving by the fault signal on its way to the CPU interrupt?

Comment: @jonathanjo Yes, an and gate would have worked. But I didnt like that solution as I felt it is too rigid, but also it adds one more thing to fail hardware wise. Although it mightve made design and simulation easier

Comment: Engineering really is just about managing the tradeoffs between one solution and another in terms of space, reliability, cost, development etc.  With component shortages in such an unpredictable state, I very much like avoiding niche features of CPUs.  You might consider a gate/transistor on the output as a kind of failsafe too, for CPU crashes/brownouts/whatever, as the failure modes of the fault input might be difficult to find out.  In the end it all depends on your judgement of the risks/benefits.

Comment: @jonathanjo I did think about it. My MCU has two fairly niche features that I will use: this fault input and multiple voltage IO (basically a built in shift register). I am not experienced enough to properly judge the pros and cons, but to me just being able to configure this in code and change its behavior made it seem safer for the time being. I will reconsider this when it is time to make the design commercial

Comment: It is *very wise* to design to the strengths of the actual engineers, manufacturers, maintainters involved.  It sounds as though you considered and made a well-thought-out decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, fortunately after deciding to write this question and working on formatting it for 3 hours, my thoughts got organized enough to understand it.

## In short

The fault input comes from the Event System (EVSYS), which allows it to have many possible inputs including many pins, peripherals, custom logic, etc... In the [Preliminary Datasheet DS40002315B](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/AVR64DD32-28-Prelim-DataSheet-DS40002315B.pdf), it is detailed how to select a "generator" which is the input to a "channel" that you choose (channel0 to channel7). There are then event users, each of which only has one input (so can only be connected to one channel), but a channel can be connected to any number of users as needed. For fault purposes, the generator can come from the Configurable Custom Logic (CCL) module or straight from a pin, then, TDC's inputs can be attached as the user(s).

For example, if you want to use PA0 for fault input you can set `channel0 = 0x40;` and `USERTCD0INPUTA = 0x01` which corresponds to channel 0 (setting `USERTCD0INPUTA = 0x00` disables the event user, so you must use n-1 as described in the below images)

Selecting what generates the signal into a channel:
[image: Selecting the channel]

Selecting which channel a specific user is connected to:
[image: Setting what uses the selected channel]

What then remains is how to configure the fault input, but now a specific fault pin has been chosen, answering my original question.

---

## Steps followed

How did I eventually answer my own question? I followed these steps:

Working backwards using the Preliminary Datasheet (linked above), the following block diagram is found, relevant part highlighted:
[image: TCD block diagram]

My first thought was that there is a specific pin for this, so I went to the IO multiplexing table. However, only the outputs are listed for the timer.
[image: IO multiplexing table showing TCD lists outputs only]

Looking up "Event Input A" reveals the following. Looking up "INPUTA" in the datasheet is a dead end, so maybe it has something to do with Configurable Custom Logic (CCL)? - (Hint from my future self: this is a deadend because it is the answer, CCL isnt relevant in this table, but is relevant elsewhere):

[image: Event system]

I got completely lost trying to understand CCL, so I kept searching until I found the document "[TB3212 Getting Started with Timer/Counter Type D (TCD)](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/TB3212-Getting-Started-with-TCD-DS90003212.pdf)". Code examples are written for the ATtiny817 with PC5 as the TCD's fault input. Going into [ATtiny817's datasheet DS40001901B](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001901B.pdf), it can be seen that PC5 is only connected to TCA (which is irrelevant), or to LUT1-IN2. Unfortunately, they consider configuration outside the scope... The following code sample appears to cause PC5 to be the fault input:
[image: Code that appears to be used to connect PC5 to the fault input]
[image: ASYNCCH2 Register]
[image: ASYNCUSER6 Register]

Aha! It appears almost any pin can be used as an input, to many modules. It is written in a way that is virtually impossible to search for, and it seems like Event Input A is described here as Timer Counter D 0 Event 0.

The fun thing is although it seems like the timer may be similar across families, the code is not portable at all. Let's go back to our chip of interest. The event system is pretty different. Firstly, an input can be selected:
[image: Selecting the channel]

and then the "user" is set by using the peripheral name:
[image: Setting what uses the selected channel]

So for example if you want to use PA0 for fault input, you can set `channel0 = 0x40;` and `USERTCD0INPUTA = 0x01` which corresponds to channel 0 (setting `USERTCD0INPUTA = 0x00` disables the event user, so you must use n-1 as described in the above image)

Not included in these images is that the channel can be connected to the CCL, which I beleive allows custom logic with multiple inputs to go into a channel. For example, you can have OR logic for multiple pins to provide the fault input, or you can route the fault signal through the CCL instead of directly for whatever reason.

Final step: summarize and explain this in the above in short section :)